# JVM не находит класс в jar-архиве.

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, java, linux

Здравствуйте.
Есть коннектор к постгресу, настроенный по мануалу на офсайте (jar-архив, прописан в CLASSPATH). Обращение к нему идёт из плагина Eclipse (Indigo SR1) через `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");`. В win7 всё работает, в Red Hat 6 из-под рута не хочет - выдаёт ClassNotFoundException. При этом физически файл в архиве есть, CLASSPATH в порядке. Версия Java - 7. С чем это может быть связано? Может, коннектор стоит поместить внутрь самого плагина?

П.С. Если важно: под виндой в эклипс проект собираю и запускаю и менять настройки могу, под линуксом есть только готовые плагины в папке plugins и ничего более. Т.е. настройки проекта изменить нельзя, он должен уже быть рабочим.

Comment: Распечатку `CLASSPATH` в студию.

Comment: там не в нём было дело, см. ниже

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFoundException` говорит о том, что в `CLASSPATH` ваш класс все-таки отсутствует. Перепроверьте.

Что касается отсутствия возможности изменить настроки, то можно загрузить класс не из `CLASSPATH`, а из любого удобного места. См. например класс [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

Comment: CLASSPATH проверялся неоднократно, там порядок. И ведь по идее, работать должно на всех осях одинаково, т.е. если цепляет в винде, должен зацепить и в линуксе. Другое дело, что, возможно, есть разница: запустить экземпляр эклипс с этими плагинами при разработке или закинуть их в plugins и запустить обычными средствами. Хотя вроде как разницы быть не должно.

Comment: @Артём Быков Магии не бывает. Если класс доступен в CLASSPATH, то он должен загружаться.

Answer (score 1):

Простите, что так поздно вспомнил=) Разобрался. Кому интересно - вот решение. Плагины eclipse не читают сторонние архивы jar, не являющиеся плагинами. Поэтому, если плагин не должен содержать драйвер jdbc, но может его затребовать, то драйвер следует обернуть в другой плагин (включить в его состав) и работать через него.
Вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: @Артём Быков Т.е. класса все-таки не было в CLASSPATH, о чем вам все и говорили.